# Mobile App Authentication Without Login Screen

Tags: authentication, mobile

I'm designing a mobile app in which the client app that the user downloads simply opens their browser and opens the web app I designed.  The web app should never be accessible except through the downloaded app.  Before I put the site out there, I want to implement the authentication so people can't get to it until I release it.

The web app is Azure/C#/MVC5/Javascript/Sql Server.  The launch program will differ by platform (Android/iPhone/Windows8Phone).

What I would like to do, if possible, is to implement authentication without requiring a password in order to lessen the burden on the user.  I'm not very concerned from a security standpoint.  The main purpose of the authentication is just to verify that the user did in fact buy the app and that they're not just browsing to the site.

I had assumed this part would be easy, but I've spent many hours searching for a solution and I'm much more confused than when I started.  From what I've read, it sounds like I may need a 'secret' or a 'nonce'.  I have no idea how to implement such things.  Basically, I'm looking for two things here- confirmation that I'm marching down the right path from someone who knows this area (or a course correction if not), and perhaps a link to a site that contains actual implementation details for the appropriate solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a secret on your client that the web backend can verify.

#### Passing the Secret for verification

You may just pass the secret to the web backend using REST like: `http://web.app.com/something?secret=XXXXXX`

If the secret checks out, you may redirect the client to the appropriate page.

#### Creating a Secret

It can just be any string you want, very much like a password you create.

#### More secure secret

You can generate a secret to pass to your web backend that is different each time by doing this:
secret = `<random string> + SHA-1(<random string> + <fixed string>)`

[Javascript Library for SHA-1](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/)

Note: `<fixed string>` is up to you to define, this is the "real" secret that only people that have access to your code will know. (Of course they can disassemble your program and/or watch its running memory space to find out, but that's beyond most)

#### Testing the secret

On your web backend, split the given secret into `<random string>` and the `SHA-1` parts. Then do `SHA-1(<random string> + <fixed string>)` (the fixed string is the same on both your client and backend). If the SHA-1 result is the same, it's verified!

#### Preventing Sharing

A user may still share the secret with others, to prevent that, we can introduce a time stamp in the `<random string>` giving `<random string> + <time stamp>`. With that, we can limit the validity of the secret to a particular time. In this case, 30 secs to a few minutes might do to accommodate Internet lag and inaccurate clock on the client.

Comment: Ok.  I can pass it in the query string if that's the only way to do it that's not overly complex.  Do I pass it back and forth with every request/response, or exchange it for a token?  I'm sure I can find some implementation details for generating secrets online if that's the right way to go.  But I'm nervous because then someone could give all their friends access to the app by just texting them the link.  Or they could put it online or on twitter.

Comment: @user2262360 Very astute of you, I have edited my answer in response to your concern of having a more secure secret.

Comment: @DannieSim- Thank you for your help.  It won't let me upvote because I have no rep, but I'll come back as soon as I do.

Comment: Cool.  It says I need 15 though.  It just occurred to me- won't another user still be able to paste the same line into the browser to bring up the site, even if they have no idea what the hash means?

Comment: Updated the answer to address "another user able to paste the same line" into the browser.

Comment: I think you can accept the answer without a rep requirement? [How Does Accepting An Answer Work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)